# How to retry "try-catch" in a finite number and delay it?

Tags: android, try-catch

I use this code to transfer data between two device.

```
public void run() {

        try {
            Socket s = new Socket(myIpAddress, SERVERPORT);

            // outgoing stream redirect to socket
            OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();

            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
            output.println("DLS");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    s.getInputStream()));

            // read line(s)
            String st = input.readLine();
            // . . .
            // Close connection
            s.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            run();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            run();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

My problem is i have to start the server first and after that, i can start the client for a successful connection.

In the

```
public void run()
```

I put `run()` to the `UnknownHostException` and to the `IOException`.
It works fine in an other code but here i get the `StackOverFlowError`.
How can i make it to RE-try in a finite number and only try every X second?

I tried this way because the `run()` and `Thread.sleep(5000);` cried for the unhandled exceptions. When i start the service, the app is froze.

```
public void run() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        Socket s = new Socket(myIpAddress, SERVERPORT);

        // outgoing stream redirect to socket
        OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();

        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
        output.println("DLS");
        s.close();

    } 

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        try {
            run();
            break; // no exception: break out of the loop.
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is this method being called from? Is it the `run()` method of a new thread?

Comment: The `run();` is in the onCreate.

Comment: "in a finite number" is a confusing phrase. perhaps you could clarify?

Comment: I mean do the run() maximum 10 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you call run() in catch, you can do-

```
Thread.sleep(1000); // 1000 milli second = 1 second
```

This will make the thread sleep for a second before it calls run again. Also, you should not try forever as this leads to a bad recursive call and there will not be enough space in stack left to carry on with any more code execution including printing the error. Maybe you should try a maximum of 5 to 10 times with an interval of 3 seconds and give up.

Stack overflow error happens when there's no virtual memory is left to carry on an execution.

Say you are calling *run* from *create* method-

```
private static final int MAX_TRY = 5;

public void create(){

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_TRY; i++){    
        if(run()){ // if run call returns true, then get out of the loop        
            break;        
        } else {           
           Thread.sleep(1000); // Wait for a second before next try       
        }    
    }
}


public boolean run() {    

    boolean isSuccessful = false;

    try {

        Socket s = new Socket(myIpAddress, SERVERPORT);

        // outgoing stream redirect to socket
        OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();

        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
        output.println("DLS");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                s.getInputStream()));

        // read line(s)
        String st = input.readLine();
        // . . .

        isSuccessful = true;

    } catch (Exception e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();            
    } finally {
        s.close();
    }

    return isSuccessful;

}
```

Comment: This is hacky. It's not solving the recursion which is leading to the `StackOverflowError` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a loop (which IMO, is simpler to understand than recursion):

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++) {
    try {
        run();
        break; // no exception: break out of the loop.
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException | IOException e) {
        Thread.sleep(DELAY_BETWEEN_ATTEMPTS_IN_MILLIS);
    }
}
```

Of course, you must not catch the exceptions anymore from the `run()` method itself.

Comment: Thank you, but i got an error:
`The method sleep(int) is undefined for the type DataLogService` DataLogService is my service.

Comment: I got this for the IOException: `Unreachable catch block for IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body` I have to put this thing to the `public void run() {`to fix this?

Comment: "Of course, you must not catch the exceptions anymore from the run() method itself.".

Comment: It is froze the app when the service starts, i updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing a function that recuses on failure with no delays. This is undesirable for a couple of reasons, one of which is that you can blow out the call-stack (as you're seeing).

Generally, i'd recommend pulling out the piece of code that can fail into its own function and have that specifically return success vs. retryable failure vs. other failure (e.g. with a custom "RetryableFailure" subclass of exception). Then you can call that from code that can retry if necessary and after a delay.

E.g.

```
class RetryableException extends Exception {
    public RetryableException(Throwable: underlying) {
        ...
    }
}


public void tryIt() throws RetryableException {

    Socket s = null;
    try {
        s = new Socket(myIpAddress, SERVERPORT);

        // outgoing stream redirect to socket
        OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();

        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
        output.println("DLS");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                s.getInputStream()));

        // read line(s)
        String st = input.readLine();
        // . . .

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        throw new RetryableException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RetryableException(e);
    } finally {
        if (s != null) {
            s.close();
        }
    }
}


public void run() {
    boolean succeeded = false;
    while (! succeeded) {
        try {
            tryIt();
            succeeded = true;
        } catch (RetryableException e) {
            // log
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Also note the following:

- i've move the socket.close to a `finally` block
- if you're calling this from `onCreate` (as you said in a comment), you'll probably want to restructure this into a `Service` rather than blocking the main thread. — http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html